# Canvas Javascript Game crashing with $.post

Tags: javascript, php, post, canvas

I'm attempting to implement a highscore system into my canvas game.

My code runs fine up until the following code:

```
$.post('api/addNewHighScore.php', 
            {   
                gamePlayer: playerName,
                gameScore: timeScore
            } 
        );
```

Unfortunately I'm not very good with using $.post, indeed I may be wrong to use it altogether. I am trying to send playerName (string) and timeScore (integer) into the corresponding column names in my online database which stores the highscore table.

The code from my 'api/addNewHighScore.php' file is as follows in case I have got this wrong too:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require('../includes/conn.inc.php');    // Connection file to highscore database

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO snakeGame(gameScore, gamePlayer) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['gameScore'], $_POST['gamePlayer']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why my website decides to freeze? Any idea what is wrong with the above code?

Many thanks

Ash

Comment: Start with the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ check for errors and the console.

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: No, no errors appear, the website crashes but the console still works for some reason?

Comment: sounds like a server side error, your post code looks fine. error likely coming from the php

Comment: how do we know if you are indeed checking for them? there's error reporting and mysqli_error($con)

Comment: I have inserted: 

<?php 
        error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); 
        ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
?>

into my html file which containes the canvas game

Comment: are you sure this file path is correct? require('../includes/conn.inc.php');

Comment: *"into my html file"* - as in what, `.html`?

Comment: Hi guys sorry if I've wasted anyone's time, I realise my description wasn't great... I'm not much of a web developer I'm more of a games programmer so I was just unsure if the above code was wrong... after delving into my javscript I noticed the function call to the $.post method was an infinite loop so problem solved but thank you all for your efforts, much appreciated!